# Authorization when two ASP.NET MVC project instances work in parallel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one ASP.NET MVC project. I have several web sites as instances of that project working on the same server, e.g. on 8000 and 8001 ports. When I authorize on 8000, if I've been authorized on 8001, I am automatically logged out on 8001 site, and vice versa. What's the problem? Is it about cookies? What are the possible ways to solve it?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: Cristian, no, I don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify for each website a custom cookie name by putting into your `web.config`:

```
<authtentication model="Forms">
    <forms name="Cookie_8000" loginUrl="urlhere" />
</authentication>
```

ASP.NET MVC is using by default cookies to store information about the signed user. When the websites are in production it should not be a problem unless they run on the same domain

However running on development workspace you can simply specify the cookie name like i said a couple lines before. Is even a better solution to configure that cookie in your `Startup.Auth.cs` class.

Here is the default configuration when you create a new project:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    }
});
```

You can specify here how the cookie works and should be:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
        // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
            regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
    },
    CookieName = "website1.cookie" // Specify the cookie name
});
```

Comment: Can you, please, describe in more details, what should be used? Currently I use standard MVC 5 authentification, and authentification mode in web.config is the following: <authentication mode="None" />

Comment: That works! Thank you very much for the solution and detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems like those sites share primary domain name. As the result, they can also share authentication cookie.

For example, `http://site1.example.com` and `http://site2.example.com`

You can do one of the followings not to share cookies between sub-domains.

**Option 1**

Specify different machine key for each site in their ***web.config***

```
<system.web>
  <machineKey decryptionKey="..." validationKey="..." />
</system.web>
```

**Option 2**

Specify full domain name in ***web.config***'s **form tag**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" domain="site1.example.com" />
 </authentication>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the situation. But nothing of the above works, unfortunately. Maybe the problem is not only in config?

Comment: Oop! You are not using FormAuthentication. Are you using OWIN Middleware? Could you show your authentication mechanism?